# Hibernate not using the max id while inserting record

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I have a table with over 54000 entries. I had imported this data from a CSV file.
When I use hibernate and try to insert a new row into this table, its not picking up the max id adding one and inserting the record, for some reason its picking up some number and trying to enter the record causing a duplicate key violation.

I believe that the sequence is corrupted so I tried running this query before the insertion happens.

```
SELECT id FROM mytable  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
SELECT setval('mytable_id_seq'," + id + ", FALSE)
```

Also, I am explicitly setting this id into the record before insertion but it still doesn't pick that up. It picks up that random number. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: you are right in that you need to adjust the sequence after importing the CSV (you can do that in a single statement: `select setval('mytable_id_seq', (select max(id) from mytable));`. If Hibernate isn't using the sequence, then you haven't configured it correctly. You need to  [edit] your question and add the Hibernate definitions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what definitions of hibernate are you looking for?

Comment: You may also want to check if a table named `hibernate_sequence` exists and if so, whether a row with your table name exists.  Hibernate could be driving your sequence values from this table rather than using a native database sequence too, depending on how you've configured hibernate and your table mappings.